# mdDialog cannot read property 'prompt' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I'm new to angularjs and so material, and I'm having trouble trying to use the mdDialog and cant find an answer. When calling the function it keeps returning mdDialog is undefined.

Follow the last code tried:

```
var corenotes = angular.module('corenotes',["ngAnimate", "ngAria", "ngMessages", 'ngMaterial', "ngMdIcons"] );

corenotes.controller('BoardController',['$scope', '$mdDialog', function($scope, $mdDialog, $http) {

[...]

  $scope.showModal = function(ev, $mdDialog){
      // Appending dialog to document.body to cover sidenav in docs app
      var confirm = $mdDialog.prompt()
            .title('What would you name your dog?')
            .textContent('Bowser is a common name.')
            .placeholder('dog name')
            .ariaLabel('Dog name')
            .targetEvent(ev)
            .ok('Okay!')
            .cancel('I\'m a cat person');
      $mdDialog.show(confirm).then(function(result) {
        $scope.status = 'You decided to name your dog ' + result + '.';
      }, function() {
        $scope.status = 'You didn\'t name your dog.';
      });
  };


}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the $mdDialog from

```
$scope.showModal = function(ev, $mdDialog) {
```

to something like this

```
function showDialog($event) {
```

Here is the documentation for $mdDialog:

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDialog

Comment: "$mdDialog.prompt is not a function"

Comment: Have you tried using show instead of prompt since prompt is not a function like the error message suggests?

Comment: I'm follow the documentation, but I just tried to use show instead of prompt, and now it's working by removing the dependency and on the function